# finding a question about constrained regression - had a side constraint $x \geq y^*z$

Tags: statistics, regression

I saw a question that asked about solving a non-negative least squares problem with $3$ unknowns, $(x,y,z)$.  But there was an additional constraint, $x \geq y^*z$.  Would appreciate getting the location on this.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use slack variables to construct the Lagrangian

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

If you turn the problem into an optimization problem,  Occupy Gezi gave the solution and this could be the simplest.

Another way would be to set $x=y z + \lambda^2$ and to run the regression using $\lambda,y,z$ as tuning parameters.